# How do I create and send a json object in actionscript?

Tags: json, apache-flex, actionscript

I am trying to send JSON from an actionscript/flex android app via POST. But I can't figure out how to create a JSON object in the right way.

it should look like this:

```
"pos"=>
{
"x"=>234,
"y"=>234
},
"gps"=>
{
"latitude"=>52.123,
"longitude"=>11.123
},
"event"=>"participation"
```

my code:

```
var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

// How do I create the data?

request.data = data;
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

I have tried sending it as String, but then the server receives it with "" around, and can't parse it as JSON. I have also tried creating it as URLVariables, but then I don't know how to make it nested.

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting FlashPlayer-version 11 you can use the built in JSON-parser:

```
var o:Object = {
    pos: { x:234, y:234 },
    gps: { latitude: 52.123, longitude:11.123 },
    event: "participation"
};

var s:String = JSON.stringify(o);
trace(s); //outputs - {"gps":{"latitude":52.123,"longitude":11.123},"pos":{"y":234,"x":234},"event":"participation"}

var o2:Object = JSON.parse(s);
trace(o2["event"]); //outputs - participation
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I solved it with writing it as a String. The main problem was figuring out how to format the string.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. It was a matter of formatting the brackets the right way.

```
var data:String = '{"pos":{"x":234, "y":234}, "gps":{"latitude":52.123, "longitude":11.123}, "event":"participation"}';
```